# Keeping tracks of traits under research

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

After I start researching traits, is there some place in the UI to look up what is under research and the time left? I know time left for completion can be seen at the crafting station, but that means I'd have to visit one when I need to check whether its time for the next research.

I am playing the **PC** version of ESO Tamriel, without any mods.

Comment: Each time a research is finished you get a message on top left of the screen (or at log in if it was finished while not online). It plays the same sound as other notifications but does not appear on notification panel. Other than that there is no built-in feature to help you keep track. Personally I just write them down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no (or at least if there is I have not found it either).

The existence of several UI add-ons (such as [this one](http://www.esoui.com/downloads/info521-HarvensResearchTimers.html)) suggest that the feature isn't available -- that the only way to see your research progress in a vanilla client is to visit a crafting station for the research in question.

You may want to consider installing a UI add-on if you really feel that you need this functionality.